# group menu items under components of joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Please tell me how to edit the joomla administrator component menus in joomla 2.5 i want to change the hierarchy of the menus and submenus can you please guide me the file of joomla 2.5 administrator component menus where i can set the hierarchy of menu items and sub menu items.

Like this

Advanced Features

```
   Akeeba Backup à Rename to just Backup
   j2xml
   JCE Editor
   Joomla! Update
   Virtuemart - aio
```

Comment: Have you attempted to change anything yet...?

Comment: yes i tried to rename the menu options under the languages file but was unable to edit the hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

You may **switch components on and off** for user specific groups:

Go to component > Options > Permissions > [Pick user group] > Access Administration Interface.

These are inherited from global options: System > Global configuration > Permissions > [Pick user groups] > Access Administration Interface.

There's infrastructure to **change order and hierarchy** of administration menus *(these are similar menu items to these on frontend part of the website)* but I haven't seen and extension that allows this yet (that doesn't mean it doesn't exist).

If you have some experience with SQL, You may alter database table of administration menus directly: take a look  `[db_prefix]__menu` table where `client_id = 1` and `menutype = main` but don't forget to backup database first!

Example of important values for Contacts component

```
id | title                  | alias               | parent_id | level | lft | rgt
---+------------------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+-----+----
1  | Menu_Item_Root         | root                | 0         | 0     | 0   | 101
7  | com_contact            | Contacts            | 1         | 1     | 47  | 52
8  | com_contact            | Contacts/Contacts   | 7         | 2     | 48  | 49
9  | com_contact_categories | Contacts/Categories | 7         | 2     | 50  | 51
```

- `lft` and `rgt` defined position in components menu
- additionally `alias`, `parent_id`, `level` define hierarchy

Comment: I have inserted a new row in #__menu table as you suggested with client_id = 1 and menutype = main but I can't see my new entry

Comment: Ok I found it. I also needed to have the correct extension id from table #_extensions at the component_id field

Comment: The table above is a shortened version of the original